# Test Session for pallet

Tags: clojure, pallet

Is there a way of testing pallet crates?  I am trying to build an elasticsearch crate but each time I want to test something is working I need to start a machine and wait for everything to install etc.  Possibly a way to just see what commands would be sent to the machine would be useful to start with and would provide a lot of insight.

Comment: My own "testing" process is basically just repeated runs using vmfest and then checking the state of the machines (which could be automated). Not great and it's really slow.

Comment: This is exactly my current technique and I it is a problem.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the pallet irc channel? that's the best place to get pallet support.

Comment: I'm asking on there now but I hate IRC, maybe I'm too young :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm discussing this topic currently also. As I'm right, pallet translates config-actions from clojure to bash - right?

So the clojure part should be testable in the normal clojure way - I found these options valid:

- http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/08/clojuretest-introduction.html
- https://github.com/marick/Midje and
- a discussion comparing these
  options: [How do Midje and Speclj compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928250/how-do-midje-and-speclj-compare)

The translation to bash itself should be well tested in pallet project - so all units are covered.
But anyway I expect there many integration-test problems left - and at this point I haven't any good idea yet.

Okay - your comment made me find an example for testing in pallet (would be interested in your experience ;-)

- https://github.com/pallet/pallet/tree/develop/test/pallet/crate

Comment: I marked as correct but basically the answer is 'not really' :)  I haven't been doing much work on this lately so haven't looked any deeper yet.

Comment: added testing example